# ImmediateRequeueAmqpException doesn't seem to work

Tags: spring-amqp

When I'm throwing ImmediateRequeueAmqpException from my listener, the message is not requeued.

Actually I'm suspecting some bug because of code in org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ContainerUtils which doesn't treat the case where ImmediateRequeueAmqpException is encapsulated in a ListenerExecutionFailedException so the test with the throwable does not work.

```
public static boolean shouldRequeue(boolean defaultRequeueRejected, Throwable throwable, Log logger) {
        boolean shouldRequeue = defaultRequeueRejected ||
                throwable instanceof MessageRejectedWhileStoppingException ||
                throwable instanceof ImmediateRequeueAmqpException;
        Throwable t = throwable;
        while (shouldRequeue && t != null) {
            if (t instanceof AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException) {
                shouldRequeue = false;
            }
            t = t.getCause();
        }
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Rejecting messages (requeue=" + shouldRequeue + ")");
        }
        return shouldRequeue;
    }
```

Does someone already use ImmediateRequeueAmqpException  with success ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug to me; the test case does not use a real listener container.

Please open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues).